# Como contar diferentes nomes numa coluna em vba?

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Boas pessoal,
estou com uma dúvida num trabalho em vba em que, numa coluna, tem quatro marcas de carros:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o suposto é colocar na celula c15 a marca que queremos procurar e na celula d15 tem que aparecer o número de carros que há dessa marca
obrigado

Comment: Já tentou usar fórmula? Colocando a marca em C15 e a fórmula `=CONT.SE(B2:B14;C15)` em D15. Em que B2:B14 é o intervalo com as marcas.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia,
pode usar a função seguinte que conta os valores unícos:

```
Public Function CountUnique(rng As Range) As Integer
        Dim dict As Dictionary
        Dim cell As Range
        Set dict = New Dictionary
        For Each cell In rng.Cells
             If Not dict.Exists(cell.Value) Then
                dict.Add cell.Value, 0
            End If
        Next
        CountUnique = dict.Count
    End Function
```

Comment: Muito bom usar Dicionário, pois é mais rápido do que interagir com a planilha Excel. Só um adendo: Esta é uma função em que um exemplo de usá-la é: `CountUnique(B3:B12)`